# Usage of virtual keyword VS simple redefining in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that `virtual` functions are declared in base class and can be (don't have to be unless it's a pure virtual function) refined in a derived class. However, I don't understand the difference between redefining a virtual function and redefining a regular function. Looking at this example code:

```
class base {
public:
 virtual int getAge(){
  return 20;
 }
 int getId(){
  return 11111;
 }
};

class dri : public base{
public:
 int getAge(){
  return 30;
 }
 int getId(){
  return 222222;
 }
};

int main(){
 dri d;
 std:: cout << d.getAge() << std::endl;
 std:: cout << d.getId() << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

will output:

```
30
222222
```

in which case having the `virtual` keyword there didn't make any difference. both functions were overwritten. So why is it needed?

Comment: @drescherjm it's added

Comment: Replace `dri d;` with `dri a; base& d = a;` to see the difference.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/

Comment: In the example `main()` function you've given, there is no difference, since the compiler knows that `d` is of type `dri`.    There are other examples where it does make a difference.

Comment: You have indeed come up with an example where there is no point whatsoever in suffering the overhead of `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give an example of your class member function invocation. I guess you write the following code:

```
dri sth;
cout << sth.getAge() << endl;
cout << sth.getId() << endl;
```

However, please note that c++'s dynamic binding and polymorphism can only be applied when the instance is a **pointer or reference**, which actually means you should do this to get your ideal output:

```
base *sth = new dri();
cout << sth->getAge() << endl;
cout << sth->getId() << endl;
```